# How can I extract ArrayList from HashMap and loop through it in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, lookup, contains

I have set up a HashMap like so:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> theAccused = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

... and I populate this by storing for every name (key), a list of names (value). So:

```
ArrayList<String> saAccused = new ArrayList<String>();
// populate 'saAccused' ArrayList
...
// done populating
theAccused.put(sAccuser, saAccused);
```

So now, I want to look through all of the entries in the HashMap and see if (for each 'sAccuser'), the list 'saAccused' contains a certain name. This is my failed attempt so far:

```
Set<String> setAccusers = theAccused.keySet();
Iterator<String> iterAccusers = setAccusers.iterator();
iterAccusers.next();
ArrayList<String> saTheAccused;

// check if 'sAccuser' has been accused by anyone before
for (int i = 0; i < theAccused.size(); i++) {
    saTheAccused = theAccused.get(iterAccusers);

    if (saTheAccused.contains(sAccuser)) {

    }
    iterAccusers.next();
}
```

... however I'm not sure how the `Set` and `Iterator` classes work :/ The problem is that I don't have the "values"... the names... the `'sAccuser'`s... for the HashMap available.

In a nutshell, I want to iterate through the HashMap and check if a specific name is stored in any of the lists. So how can I do this? Let me know if you need me to go into further detail or clear up any confusion.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 Sheesh!  A bunch of answers but not one of the answerers bothered to upvote the question?  An upvote means the question is well-written,  specific, and shows what the user has already tried.  This question meets all the requirements for an upvote.

Comment: @Jim... :) Thank you! Wow... it feels really nice to finally have someone recognize me this way. Thank you so much... I wish some more people thought like you :) Thanks! +1 for specifying that my question meets all requirements for an upvote.

Comment: @Jim Garrison you are right, but for me there are two more requirements - the question should be hard, and of common interest - i.e. when you have the problem, googling should lead to this question.

Comment: @Bozho... I'll keep in mind what you think about quality questions. I thought this was a hard question, since I've never dealt with this before, but you are right... I probably could have Google'd it first. I just felt like I would get an exact answer quicker if I asked SO. As far as common interest... doesn't that just depend on the SO community? If you're not interested, someone else will be (hopefully). Thanks for your input :)

Comment: @Bozho: You are correct, but I relax those requirements for newer SO users.  Plus, there are so many bad and mediocre questions that I try to give positive feedback whenever appropriate, to encourage good questions. I was just surprised that so many people took time to answer without upvoting.

Comment: @Hristo that is my policy of upvoting questions, others have different ones - that's good about SO. And you are partially correct that sometimes asking on SO will be quicker than googling. The fact one does not upvote does not mean he is not interested in answering the question - I did answer it ;)

Comment: @Bozho... and I appreciate your answer :) It was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In a nutshell, I want to iterate through the HashMap and check if a specific name is stored in any of the lists. So how can I do this?

There's two ways of iterating through the map that might be of interest here.  Firstly, you can iterate through all of the mappings (i.e. pairs of key-value relations) using the [entrySet()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) method, which will let you know what the key is for each arraylist.  Alternatively, if you don't need the key, you can simply get all of the lists in turn via the `values()` method.  Using the first option might look something like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : theAccused.entrySet())
{
   String sListName = entry.getKey();
   ArrayList<String> saAccused = entry.getValue();
   if (saAccused.contains(sAccuser))
   {
      // Fire your logic for when you find a match, which can
      // depend on the list's key (name) as well
   }
}
```

To answer the broader questions - the [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface simply represents an (unordered) collection of non-duplicated values.  As you can see by the linked Javadoc, there are methods available that you might expect for such an unordered collection.  An [Iterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) is an object that traverses some data structure presenting each element in turn.  Typical usage of an iterator would look something like the following:

```
Iterator<?> it = ...; // get the iterator somehow; often by calling iterator() on a Collection
while (it.hasNext())
{
   Object obj = it.next();
   // Do something with the obj
}
```

that is, check whether the iterator is nonexhausted (has more elements) then call the `next()` method to get that element.  However, since the above pattern is so common, it can be elided with Java 5's [foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work), sparing you from dealing with the iterator itself, as I took advantage of in my first example.

Comment: Wow... Thanks for that response! Quick question... when you say `Iterater<String> it = ...;`, is it equal to an element, in my case, is it equal to an element from the Set? Thanks for the link to 'for-each'. I've never used it. Stellar answer!

Comment: Also... if we go back to your for loop... if I do find a match, how can I extract the name (key) of the ArrayList that contains 'sAccuser'?

Comment: @Hristo - the `it` variable would be an object that would return successive elements of the underlying collection every time its `next()` method was called, not an element itself.  As for your second question, I've modified my example to show it using `entrySet()`, as this is the way to iterate over a Map when you care about both keys *and* values.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
for (List<String> list : theAccused.values()) {
    if (list.contains("somename")) {
        // found somename
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should make it work:

```
saTheAccused = theAccused.get(iterAccused.next());
```

However, to make your code more readable, you can have either:

```
for (List<String> values : theAccused.values()) {
    if (value.contains(sAcuser)) {
       ..
    }
}
```

or, if you need the key:

```
for (String key : theAccused.keySet()) {
    List<String> accused = theAccused.get(key);
    if (accused.contains(sAccuser)) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I needed. Do revise your answer though... I was looking for an ArrayList... I don't want you getting downvoted for a stupid reason :)

Comment: @Hristo you get an `ArrayList`, but you reference it by its interface - `List`, which is considered a better practice (unless your really need the methods specific to `ArrayList`)

Comment: If you need both the key and the value, you should use the entrySet, rather than the keySet and a get.

Comment: .. oh interesting... I wasn't aware of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the value from `Iterator.next()` to index into the `Map`.

```
String key = iterAccusers.next();
saTheAccused = theAccused.get(key);
```

Currently you're getting values from the `Map` based on the *iterator*, not the values returned by the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Make a method that does it:

```
 private String findListWithKeyword(Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map, String keyword) {
   Iterator<String> iterAccusers = map.keySet().iterator();
   while(iterAccusers.hasNext()) {
      String key = iterAccusers.next();
      ArrayList<String> list = theAccused.get(key);
      if (list.contains(keyword)) {
         return key;
      } 
   }
}
```

And when you call the method:

```
String key = findListWithKeyword(map, "foobar");
ArrayList<String> theCorrectList = map.get(key);
```

Comment: .. thanks for your response. I'm already writing a method that is doing this. This is the point of my question :) Quick question... when you say `Iterater<String> iterAccusers = ...;`, is iterAccusers equal to an element, in my case, is it equal to an element from the Set, or is it uninitialized to begin with?

Comment: Also, one more question... if I do find a match, how can I extract the name (key) of the ArrayList that contains 'sAccuser' that it belongs to?

Comment: iterAccusers is an Iterator i.e. you can call next() on it and get the next element. It's just like a for-each loop. The iterator is NOT an element in the set, it's an object used to iterate through the set.

As for extracting the key. Instead of returning the list, just return the key. See the edited code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to do two things: first, find out if a given name is "accused", and second, find out who the accuser is.  For that, you need to iterate over the Entry objects within your Map.

```
    for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : theAccused.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().contains(accused)) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }

    return null; // Or throw NullPointerException, or whatever.
```

In this loop, the Entry object holds a single key-value mapping.  So entry.getValue() contains the list of accused, and entry.getKey() contains their accuser.

Comment: .. what is an Entry object? I haven't encountered that yet.

Comment: It's actually an inner Class of Map.  The full class name is java.util.Map.Entry.  (The JavaDoc is here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)  In my experience, it's seldom used.  However, in this case it serves nicely, and since it's part of the Map API, there's no reason not to use it.